# Do Displayport versions apply to cables?

Tags: display-port, video-adapters, cable, adapter

I have a Dell P2415Q monitor, it is UHD monitor, which has mini displayport as one of its input sources. I do not have any other outputs with mDP connector, and I want to only use full sized DP cables, and only use a mDP to DP cable adapter for this one mDP connection to monitor. I want it to be on cable (not in a form of solid case adapter) because there is no space for solid case adapter there.

I have found an adapter cable which is branded as Dell and marked with the following id: DAYANBC084, 0YY1FJ / YY1FJ, 0857GN / 857GN.

In the item description I see it is written 'DisplayPort Version 1.1 (Supports up to 3840x2160@30Hz)'. But I need the UHD@60Hz for my monitor.

I am interested, is that information really correct? **Can the displayport version specifications be applied to cables themselves?** In other words, this one will not work for me? Because I cannot quite understand that. The cable is just a copper wires and it cannot "understand" a specification. It only can be more or less qualitative. And as this one is Dell branded, it should be of good quality.

If I am mistaken, than how do I understand that cable supports 1.2 specification? The other cable adapters I saw had no any mentioning about their supported dp specification.

Additionaly, do I need to bother about having ferrite ring that is presented on some mini displayport to displayport adapter cables?

Comment: The ferrite core will only help; And the quality of the cable does affect the actual max bandwidth so there are some cables that won't be reliable for DP 1.2 signals or newer even if the connection can be started.

Answer (score 1):

Linus Tech Tips once did an experiment with HDMI cables, trying to run HDMI 2.1 over HDMI 2.0 cables. Most of them didn't succeed, so it would be better getting a cable that supports the specs.

Back to DP though, DP and mDP are basically the same thing (except the size) so any passive adapter will work, even third party ones, like this one: https://www.amazon.nl/Rankie-DisplayPort-Adapter-Resolutie-Gereed/dp/B00YOVKWQS/